# Does nginx auth_basic work over HTTPS?

Tags: nginx, https, password-protected

I've been trying to setup a password protected directory in a SSL website as follows:

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
    listen 443:
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /usr/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/certs/server.key;

    server_name server1.example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com/htdocs/;
    index index.html;

    location /secure/ {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/example.com/.htpasswd;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I try to access the URL `https://server1.example.com/secure/`, I get a "404: Not Found" error page.

My error.log shows the following error:

```
011/11/26 03:09:06 [error] 10913#0: *1 no user/password was provided for basic authentication,
client: 192.168.0.24, server: server1.example.com, request: "GET /secure/ HTTP/1.1",
host: "server1.example.com"
```

However, I was able to setup password protected directories for a normal HTTP virtual host without any problems.

Is it a problem with the config or something else?

Comment: Sure, `auth_basic` module works fine over https. I don't see the `error_log` directive in your `server` block. Where did you get the above error? I would suggest you tuning error_log to `debug` level to see what does it say. Did you clear cache or try with different browser?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly it's a path problem for auth_basic_user_file, where your absolute path is confusing nginx:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAuthBasicModule#auth_basic_user_file

> Since version 0.6.7 the filename path is relative to directory of nginx configuration file nginx.conf, but not to nginx prefix directory.

I'm not sure how you have it working in the other cases.  The quote from the documentation suggests that you should have to have something like:

```
auth_basic_user_file htpasswd/www.example.com
```

where you'd have the password file as "/etc/nginx/htpasswd/www.example.com" if you have "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" as your server configuration file.

You can check nginx configuration by running "sudo nginx -t".  If there's a configuration error, i.e., the auth file is not where it expects it to be, it should tell you at that point.